# SSO on Bugzilla

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bugzilla

This is regards to SSO supports required on the Bugzilla. I am ROR developer working on one of my project where I requires the SSO functionality for Bugzilla. Let me explore the scenario:

My application is running on rails 2.3.5 and ruby 1.8.7. I have the domain name beta.abc.com with their specific database and on the other hand i installed Bugzilla for my application that is having the domain name bugs.abc.com(that redirects me to Bugzilla home page) and having the separate database i.e. bugs. 
Now my query is that I want the single sign on for my Bugzilla account that the user will not required to register on Bugzilla for new account instead of it they can use beta.abc.com credentials in Bugzilla and able to login to Bugzilla same credentials.

I go through with multiple documentation to fix this issue but all in vain .I don’t find any feasible solution to overcome from this problem.Kindly to let me know and provide me any feasible solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RADIUS server or LDAP server for authentication (exclusively or in addition to the standard authentication) to centralize the authentication process. See http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/parameters.html for more information.